# Simple Maths Operators implementation in Quantum

Tags: qiskit, mathematics, resource-request

I am a newbie in quantum programming and trying to learn implementing some simple classical programs in quantum, just as a starting point. The thing I am kind of struggling in is availability of functions in any language. I have started with Qiskit and also have seem some algorithms implemented in projectq. The detail of programming goes to gates level a simple full adder implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/GDLMadushanka/17bb2ddc9450054abcf1ab04779e2182), however is there any library with simple functions implemented in it like add, subtract, multiply, shift operators etc. Functions that take quantum registers and apply above operations on them. Or its just the way to first think of any operation at gates level and then implement it in as quantum circuit?

If this is the case can anyone share some good reference to get a starting point?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: [https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/circuits/3_summary_of_quantum_operations.html](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/circuits/3_summary_of_quantum_operations.html) ?

Comment: @Roland: your link concerns quantum gates but *anděla* is looking for implementation of arithmetic operations on a quantum computer.